# Silicone and bathroom tile: how long is it viable?

Tags: bathroom, tile, silicone

A few months ago we had a home inspector in who mentioned that some of our tile grout was starting to fail around our tub/shower, and that it should be replaced as soon as possible, preferably with a new tub surround in place of the tile.

I've been having a difficult time finding a contractor to do this work, so in the mean-time patched any hair-line cracks and missing grout with GE 100% White Silicone Caulk (I figured that actually trying to re-grout was going to be a losing battle, and I wasn't quite confident enough that I'd do it correctly).

My question is: how long does the silicone job give me to track down a contractor and have the work done? I've read that silicone is definitely a temporary solution, but will it actually hold for a lengthy period of time? And is it recommended to re-apply if necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It CAN hold for quite some time - or not. Much depends on surface preparation (how clean things were) when applying it. Since it's not really a good solution, it's hard to say how long it might last - could be months, could be years.

**If** the only problem is the grout, sawing out the bad grout (yes, really, look for a grout saw) and re-grouting is a good deal less work than redoing the whole surround. If there are other problems (such as improper waterproofing behind the tile, or occupants [rather than a home inspector who does not live there] not liking the tile) that math changes.

Re-grouting is not terribly difficult to learn. Just protect the tub really well, as you will certainly drop some grout (and it needs protection when you are sawing out the old grout as well - or if you do remove the tile.)

Comment: Thanks. I did learn to re-grout and bought the right tools, but the tile is about 60 years old and it looked like over time more and more of the grout was ready to fail. It caused me a bit of a grief as I wasn't sure how serious of an issue water damage to the wall could be. That led me to look into a new surround.

Comment: If **any** of the grout is failing, you normally saw it **all** out and replace it **all** (since it's all suspect once one part of it fails.) If the tile is not falling off the wall and there are not other signs of problems with water getting behind the tile, there's no need to expand the problem beyond that...at 60 years old it was probably installed quite well, albeit not in the same way that it would be now.

Comment: It seems like you or the inspector are under the impression that this is a waterproofing issue. It is not. Tile and grout or caulk should not be considered waterproof. There should be some sort of waterproof structure BEHIND the tile to do this job, which should terminate at the tub flange to drain any water that gets behind the tile. I should say at least if the prepwork was done right, this should not be a waterproofing issue. If there is no waterproofing behind the tile, everything should be redone anyway (and there's a good chance the framing will be rotted and moldy).

Comment: 60 year old waterproofing is not up to modern standards, **but** if it hasn't failed, there's no innate reason to assume it will next week.